# How can I pass a variable from @Input to a service in an Angular2 component>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So, What I am trying to do seems like it would be trivial. And it probably is. But I can't figure it out. My question is:How can I pass a variable from @Input to a service in an Angular2 component? (Code has been simplified)

My component is as follows:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CMSService } from '../cms.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'cmstext',
  templateUrl: './cmstext.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cmstext.component.css']
})
export class CMSTextComponent {
  constructor(private cms: CMSService) { }

  @Input() id : string;
  content = this.cms.getContent(this.id); // this.id is NULL so content is NULL
}
```

And then my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CMSService {
    constructor() { }

    getContent(textId:string) : string {
        this.text = textId; // textId is NULL so this.text returns NULL
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

My component template:

```
<p>id: {{id}}</p>
<p>Content: {{content}}</p>
```

When `<cmstext id="4"></cmstext>` is added to another component template the output is:

```
id: 4
content:
```

I'm just diving into Angular2 any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A setter should work. But basically you are too early. Should also work if you set it in `ngOnInit() { this.cms.getContent(this.id); }`

Comment: Thanks @Kris This is what worked for me. Do you want to add a more specific answer or do you want me to paste the actual code I'm using?

Comment: Looks good. Did you have luck with `set`? That should work.. Not sure which way is preferred to be honest.

Comment: I had a little luck with the `set`. i'm sure it would work with a few adjustments. I was able to get the `content` to the template, just not the `id` from the element attribute. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Kris Hollenbeck,`ngOnInit()` was the answer. My final code looked like this. The component now passed the variable to the service.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CMSService } from '../cms.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'cmstext',
  templateUrl: './cmstext.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cmstext.component.css']
})
export class CMSTextComponent implements OnInit  {

  public content : string;

  @Input() id : string;

  constructor(private cms: CMSService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.content = this.cms.getContent(this.id);
  }
}
```

This assigned the data from the service to the variable "content" and the id passed from the element attribute to the variable "id". Both variables were then accessible to the template!

Comment: Thanks Kris. It did look hella funny to me :D

Answer (score 2):

Just make it a setter and put the code there:

```
  @Input() 
  set id(value : string) {
    this.content = this.cms.getContent(value);
  }
```

Comment: Hard to tell from here without more information. Where do you assign a value to `textId`?

Comment: Its set by an attribute on the component element its self:

Comment: `<cmstext id="4"></cmstext>`

Comment: then id is passed to the service where it is assigned to textId. The problem whasnt there. it worked if I hard coded a value and bypassed the input variable altogether.

Comment: I forgot to update a part of the code I copied from your question. `getContent(value)`

Comment: I tried that too. ngOnInit worked though. I'll have to dig into setters a little more later. Thanks for the help

Comment: Perhaps the `id` name for the input is the problem. You could try a different one.

Comment: Maybe. I actually was able to get it to work with your suggestion. Except I had to explicitly declare content as a class attribute and use `this.content` in the setter. Except, with this solution the `id` then becomes unavailable to the template. Which could be dealt with by returning an object from the service and sending data to the template that way.

Comment: Right `this` was missing. I don't know what you mean with `with this solution the `id` then becomes unavailable to the template`. You can add `this.id = this.content` to `set id`, but if you just use `content` in the template, you get the same value.

Comment: if you look at the component template you'll notice that `content` and the  `id` pulled from the attribute. They are not the same data. The `id` still wasn't available to the template.